# How do I set an image to a background

Tags: java, image, swing, background, jpanel

I'm trying to create a simple JFrame with the content pane JPanel. I want to know how to set an IMAGE as a background. I know that a lot of people have a already asked this, but I get unresolved compilation errors whenever I try.
In the end, I created a whole new class in my class, but that had errors too. 
How do I do this? Please help.

```
package menu;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import models.AskTheAdmiralFrame;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
/**
 * 
 * @author Russell
 *
 */

public class HistoraskMenu extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8106152174535131551L;
private static JPanel panel;
private JButton ATA = new JButton("Ask The Admiral");
public Color oldPaper = new Color(255, 230, 179); 
private JLabel label = new JLabel();
private final JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("");
private final ImageIcon bg = new ImageIcon("/Users/Russell/Desktop/Russell/Java/Coding"
            + "/eclipse workspace/Historask/resources/bg.jpg");
Image img = bg.getImage();

public HistoraskMenu(){
    setBounds(50, 50, 700, 500);    
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    setTitle("Historask");

    panel = new JPanel();

    setContentPane(panel);

    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);    //Sets position of Historask sign
    label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
    label.setBackground(new Color(238, 232, 170));          //Sets the colour of the foreground and background of Historask sign
    label.setForeground(oldPaper);
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Users/Russell/Desktop/Russell/Java/Coding"
            + "/eclipse workspace/Historask/resources/title.png"));
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.setBounds(50, 10, 500, 50);
    getContentPane().add(label);

    panel.add(label_1);

    ATA.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {            //What happens when you press ATA button
            new AskTheAdmiralFrame();
        }
    });

    getContentPane().add(ATA);

    setVisible(true);
}

public class panel extends JPanel{
    setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        super.paintComponents(g);
      }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting and at what lines?

Comment: In `paintComponent` call `super` first, then draw the image.

Comment: -1, this question is asked regularly. `I know that a lot of people have a already asked this, but I get unresolved compilation errors whenever I try.` - then fix the errors. Or you can always search for another example. Did you look under the "Related" heading on the right side of this page?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to panel object in the HistoraskMenu() constructor it wont draw image because you are innitializing this to JPanel directly. Rather try panel = new panel();